# Install Gnome and KDE on old system

Tags: gnome, software-installation, kde, eclipse, software-sources

I have old Ubuntu linux:

```
uname —a
2.6.32—35—generic—pae #78—Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 11 17:O1:12 UTC 2011 i 686 GNU/Linux
```

I need to install desktop enviropment in order to run Eclipse on it.

How I can install Gnome and KDE on my old machine. I suppose I need to install them from special sources. How to find these sources and how to define them on my system?

UPD

I did apt-get update
and got in output:

[image]

How to fix it?

UPD 2

I'm using Ubuntu 10.04.3 LTS

UPD 3

I have changed sources paths to old release, but still have this:
[image]

Comment: You will need to update and install from the old-releases repositories [instructions can be found here](//askubuntu.com/q/91815/320386). Be warned, this question may be closed as Off-topic, this site only answers questions about currently supported version of Ubuntu.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 10.04.3 LTS

Answer (score 1):

You're using Ubuntu 10.04.  That version is well past End of Life.  That means there are no longer even security updates, and your question is technically off topic for this Exchange.

What I'd recommend is to back up your stored data and install Kubuntu 14.04 -- or, if the machine isn't up to a modern Kubuntu, try Lubuntu or Xubuntu.  If you can't run Eclipse with a modern system that your hardware can handle, it's likely you'll be disappointed in the overall performance anyway (though my experience is that Kubuntu 14.04 runs reasonably well on my roughly ten year old Dell Latitude D520, a dual core with 2 GB RAM).

Comment: I can't since I need to build test application on this particular system. I don't want new system, I need to have exact this system with desktop.

Comment: I would recommend upgrading whatever system you're building for, as well.  If this is a school system, talk to the system admins and ask them to update to a supported version.

Answer (score 0):

am not sure that would help , but try :

`sudo apt-get install ubuntu-gnome-desktop`

or

`sudo apt-get install gnome-desktop-environment`

best regards,

Comment: got "Couldn't find package gnome-desktop-environment" and "Couldn't find package ubuntu-gnome-desktop"

Comment: hello , its seems you are using old ubuntu version , so i suggest you add some repos in your sources.list that compatible to ur ubuntu or search for a stable gnome repo so you can do that, the sudo apt-get update. check this post (http://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release)

Comment: i suggest you backup your sources.list first `sudo cp /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.original`